# Curiosity about executing binary

Tags: windows, linux, unix

This is just a curiosity of mine about how a specific OS executes a binary file.
If I change dir to some path in UNIX or Windows I can execute a program just by entering its file name. In Linux I have to enter `./file_name` (unless it's included in `PATH`). In know it's kind of a stupid question, but is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing magical - it's simply because, by default, Windows implicitly includes '.' in the executable search path. *nix does not.

The latter behavior is obviously more secure, if marginally less convenient.

You can obtain behavior similar to Windows under *nix (at some cost in security) by adding '.' to your path

For example, you could add the following to your .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=PATH:.
```

Of course, that's not *exactly* the same as Windows, as Windows (again, by default) looks in the CWD *first*. You could do the same in *nix by moving the '.' to the front of the system's PATH, but **don't do that**!

It opens you up to a large security risk. If someone were to be able to drop a malicious program with the same name as a system utility (say "ls", or "cp"), that program would run instead of the system utility. You can imagine the potential for "mischief" that provides!

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what Gregj said, there is a `PATH` variable in both Windows and Linux, which tells the operating system where to look for executables when you don't tell it explicitly where it is.  Linux doesn't include the current directory (`.`) for security concerns; a program could otherwise hide an executable with the name of a common utility (`ls`, for instance) in a lot of files so you might overlook it, and then it would be run instead of the utility you meant, potentially causing damage, loss of sensitive data, etc.  Windows does search `.`, even if it's not explicitly in the path, for convenience and because of their lack of concern over security.

Comment: Great, except the part about security: in Linux, you'd have to make `./ls` executable before being able to run it, even if `.` was in your path.

Comment: Yes, it has to be executable, but why would *you* have to make it executable? If it's meant to be an attack like that, why wouldn't it come executable, probably from something like a tar archive.